# task schedulers task status in excel

Tags: vba, windows, scheduled-tasks

I have command for the command prompt from which i can get the task status. I want to save the output of the command to excel.

```
[![schtasks /query /tn "Estimates" /v /fo list | find "Status:"][1]][1]
```

I tried using the following code for executing this command.

```
PID = Shell("cmd /k schtasks /query /tn ""Estimates"" /v /fo list | find ""Status:""", vbNormalNoFocus)
MsgBox PID
```

This code gives me some random number as output in PID and opens the CMD and shows the command execution details. How i can get the output values of the command. Please see image below for the output.

[image]

Comment: Debug.Print CreateObject("wscript.shell").exec("cmd /V /C schtasks /query /tn ""Estimates"" /v /fo list | find ""Status:""").StdOut.ReadAll      ?

Comment: Here we go again. Programmers do not use user's commands. They are for users. Use programatic intefaces https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/displaying-task-names-and-state--scripting-